# has many returning empty

Tags: relationship

i have two models
1. `Question`  , primary key is `questionId` and has relation

```
public function option(){

        return $this->hasMany('Option', 'question_id', 'question_id');

    }
```

and

```
AnswerOption
```

has  primary key is `option_id` and foriegn key is `questionId` and when i try to accesss this relation in controller

```
  $data=  Question::where('question_id',3)->with('option')->get();
```

it always return empty array for answers

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 3
            [option_id] => 3
            [question] => ww
            [questionType] => gfg
            [option] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

but i have data in answeroptions table also foriegn key 3

Can any one help me where i am doing wrong

Comment: It looks like your hasMany relationship is wrong, it should be like: return $this->hasMany('App\Models\AnswerOption', 'questionId', 'optionId');

Comment: @btl. no i have defined foreing key as questionId in second table .option id is primary key for second table

Comment: Silly question, but do you have any rows in your option table where the `questionid` is 3?

Comment: @aynber. i have . i am using lumen

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your relation is wrong. You have to specify the related table id.

```
$this->hasMany('model', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Also I would suggest you to use Laravel's conventions for naming tables and fields.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many